# How do I implement vectors (vector-math)?

Tags: android, math, opengl-es, vector

Currently i'm making a breakout game, and to define objects' location or movement i'm using :

```
float mX, mY;
float speedX, speedY;
```

And to move an object I add the speed in a certain direction to the current position (mX += speedX).

But I've read alot on that I 'should' be using vectors instead of the above, wich I now plan on doing.  I've read up on some of this vector math, but I don't know how I could implement this in my game. There's alot of information on the math itself, but I couldn't find anything on the code-side of it.  I could come up with:

```
float mX, mY;
float direction;
float velocity;
```

But here i'm kinda stuck. I know I should move the object to `direction` with `velocity`, probably with a factor of time, but how ?

(btw, i''m making it with openGL-ES on Android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A vector in 2D has two dimensions: `(vx, vy)`.  That's all you need.

You find the direction by calculating what's called  'unit vector': a vector of magnitude 1 that points in the direction you're going.

You calculate magnitude using this formula: `magnitude = sqrt(vx*vx + vy*vy)`

You get the unit vector by dividing both components by the magnitude:

```
(ux, uy) = (vx/magnitude, vy/magnitude)
```

If you are moving with a constant velocity over a time step dt, then the distance you move in each direction is:

```
(dx, dy) = (vx*dt, vy*dt)
```

This assumes no acceleration over that time period.

This is all basic vector stuff.  A little reading could go a long way.

Comment: Do you maybe know some good examples, tutorials or websites on this?

Comment: There are millions of books and web pages written on elementary vectors.  Pick one.  This won't be a matter of scanning a page and being an expert.  You'll have to do some work to learn it, but it'll be worth it.  Fire up Google and see what it brings back.